# PUT command with Indy 8.0.26 in Delphi 6

Tags: delphi, indy, put, delphi-6, indy-8

I can send a `POST` request with `TIdHTTP` in Indy 8, but I don't know how to send a `PUT` request.

```
var
  Params:TStrings;
  Resp: TMemoryStream;//TMemoryStream;
  URI, sResp: AnsiString;
begin
   try
      Params := TStringList.Create;
      Params.Add(EdPost.Text);
      //Params.Add('Method=PUT');   ???
      Resp := TMemoryStream.Create;
      URI := EdUri.Text + Edit6.Text;   //
      Http1.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
      Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + sTocken;
      //Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['Method'] :='PUT';    ???
      Http1.Post(URI, Params, Resp);
```

Answer (score 2):

`TIdHTTP` in Indy 8 simply does not support `PUT` requests.  It only supports `HEAD`, `GET`, and `POST` requests.  And unfortunately, you can't force a `PUT` request manually (without altering Indy's source code) as the `TIdHTTP.DoRequest()` method takes a `TIdHTTPMethod` enum that defines only those 3 HTTP requests.

Indy 9 added support for additional HTTP requests: `OPTIONS`, `TRACE`, **`PUT`**, `DELETE`, and `CONNECT`.

Indy 10 added support for user-specified HTTP methods, so `TIdHTTP` is no longer limited to a hard-coded subset of requests.

The current version of Indy (at the time of this writing) is 10.6.2.5457, and still supports Delphi 6 <sup>(1)</sup>.

I STRONGLY urge you to upgrade away from Indy 8, as it is EXTREMELY old and no longer supported by Indy's developers.  Please don't use it.  If you do not want to upgrade all the way to Indy 10, then at least upgrade to Indy 9 (though it is no longer supported either, except for bug fixes).

That being said, there is **one** possible workaround for Indy 8: **IF** the HTTP server you are sending your data to supports "verb tunneling", then you can use `TIdHTTP.Post()` to send a `POST` request while instructing the server to treat the request as if it were `PUT` instead, eg:

```
// Sadly, there is no *standard* HTTP header for verb tunneling.
// Different vendors use different headers:
//
// Most vendors use 'X-HTTP-Method-Override'
// Microsoft uses 'X-HTTP-Method'
// IBM uses 'X-METHOD-OVERRIDE'
//
// Send whichever one is appropriate for your particular server, or
// just send them all and let the server work it out...

Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['X-HTTP-Method-Override'] := 'PUT';
Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['X-HTTP-Method'] := 'PUT';
Http1.Request.ExtraHeaders.Values['X-METHOD-OVERRIDE'] := 'PUT';
Http1.Post(URI, ...);
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup>: support for pre-Unicode versions of Delphi, which includes Delphi 6, will be dropped in a future Indy 11 maintenance release.  Indy 10 will be the last version to support old compilers.